# Memcached - Why data is not stored?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, memcached

I'm actually trying to understand why memcached is not storing data for a give Id.

I'm using Magento EE 1.11.2.0 that is based on Zend Framework 1.11.1.
The interface used to deal with memcached is `Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached`

Now there is not such big custom code here, this is my custom container that save the cache:

```
public function saveCache($blockContent)
{

    $lifeTime = 86400 * 30 * 6;
    $tags = array(
        My_Module_Model_PageCache_Container_Category_Blabla::CACHE_TAG
    );
    $cacheId = $this->_getCacheId();

    if ($cacheId !== false) {
        $this->_saveCache($blockContent, $cacheId, $tags, $lifeTime);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I'm just forcing magento to use my custom `cache tag` and a fixed `lifetime` ( memcache doens't support custom tag so I guess this is not the problem ) also my `lifetime` is not used in memcached because I can see that the default one is used.

At the beginning I thought the issue was caused by a to long cache ID but now after reducing it ( <31 char ) this didn't help me:

I can see that the `load()` method `Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached` return always false for my cache ids.
While the `save()` method return true like if it was cached.

This is my local.xml configuration:

```
<cache>
        <slow_backend_store_data>1</slow_backend_store_data>
        <auto_refresh_fast_cache>0</auto_refresh_fast_cache>
        <backend>memcached</backend>
        <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
        <memcached>
            <servers>
                <!--<server>-->
                <!--<host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>-->
                <!--<port><![CDATA[11213]]></port>-->
                <!--<persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>-->
                <!--</server>-->

                <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[unix:///tmp/memcached.sock]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[0]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[0]]></persistent>
                    <weight><![CDATA[2]]></weight>
                    <timeout><![CDATA[5]]></timeout>
                </server>
            </servers>
            <compression><![CDATA[0]]></compression>
            <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
            <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
            <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
        </memcached>
    </cache>
    <full_page_cache>
        <backend>memcached</backend>
        <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
        <slow_backend_store_data><![CDATA[1]]></slow_backend_store_data>
        <memcached>
            <servers>
                <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[unix:///tmp/memcached.sock]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[0]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[0]]></persistent>
                    <weight><![CDATA[2]]></weight>
                    <timeout><![CDATA[10]]></timeout>
                    <retry_interval><![CDATA[10]]></retry_interval>
                    <status><![CDATA[1]]></status>
                    <stats_update_factor><![CDATA[1]]></stats_update_factor>
                </server>
            </servers>
        </memcached>
    </full_page_cache>
```

I also tried to check the entry of memcached to see if my id was stored or not with this command:

`echo 'stats cachedump 35 35' | sudo nc -U /tmp/memcached.sock`

- Any idea about the reason of this ?
- How can I debug it ? ( I cannot go under `Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached` with xdebug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here the issue is  $lifetime and a relative bug in Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached.

Memcached has a max lifetime of 30 days (2592000) so the limit I was using it was too big and that is why the data was not stored.

Sadly:

1. Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached::save()
   doesn't check if the limit is correct < 2592000
2. the set() method on the memcached object **return true even if it doesn't store the data**
   $result = @$this->_memcache->set($id, array($data, time(), $lifetime), $flag, $lifetime);

Answer (score 3):

You can restart memcached with -vv and look at the interactions.

BTW, the default port for memcache is 11211.  FYI